discord-player track instantly ending after starting (only sometimes)
I am having a lot of trouble with this bug, and is almost impossible to track through error-tracking. The track begins, and as soon as it begins, it will end (only sometimes). This is not track-specific and can happen at seemingly random times when the /play command executes. Any help?
This is /play command.
import { PlayerMetadata } from '#bot/player/PlayerMetadata';
import { fetchPlayerOptions } from '#bot/player/playerOptions';
import { EmbedGenerator } from '#bot/utils/EmbedGenerator';
import { ApplicationCommandOptionType } from 'discord.js';

import { useMainPlayer, QueueRepeatMode } from 'discord-player';
export const data = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Play a song',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'query',
            description: 'The track or playlist to play [query or url]. Playlist ID must be prefixed with "playlist:"',
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
            autocomplete: true,
            required: true,
        },
    ],
};

export async function run({ interaction }) {
    if (!interaction.inCachedGuild())
        return;
    
    useMainPlayer().on('error', async (error) => {
        console.error('An error occurred within the player:', error);
        return;
    });
    
    const player = useMainPlayer();
    const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
    const query = interaction.options.getString('query', true);
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
    
    try {
        const result = await player.search(query, {
            requestedBy: interaction.user,
        });
        
        if (result.hasPlaylist() && result.playlist.tracks.length > 100) {
            const embed = EmbedGenerator.Error({
                title: '',
                description: '❌ The playlist has more than 100 tracks, which exceeds the limit.',
            });
            return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
        
        if (!result.hasTracks()) {
            const embed = EmbedGenerator.Error({
                title: '',
                description: `❌ No results found for \`${query}\`.`,
                footer: {
                    text: '(ℹ️) Double check the URL/Query',
                }
            });
            return interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
        
        const MAX_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const longTracks = result.tracks.filter(track => track.durationMS > MAX_TIME);
        
        if (longTracks.length > 0) {
            const embed = EmbedGenerator.Error({
                title: '',
                description: '❌ One or more tracks exceed the 2-hour limit.',
                fields: longTracks.map(track => ({
                    name: track.title,
                    value: `Duration: ${(track.durationMS / (60 * 1000)).toFixed(2)} minutes`,
                })),
                footer: {
                    text: '(ℹ️) Ensure that the track is shorter than 2 hours.',
                }
            });
            return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
        
        const playerOptions = await fetchPlayerOptions(interaction.guildId);
        const { track, searchResult } = await player.play(channel, result, {
            nodeOptions: {
                metadata: PlayerMetadata.create(interaction),
                volume: playerOptions.volume,
                repeatMode: QueueRepeatMode[playerOptions.loopMode],
                a_filter: playerOptions.filters,
                equalizer: playerOptions.equalizer.map((eq, i) => ({
                    band: i,
                    gain: eq,
                })),
                noEmitInsert: true,
                leaveOnStop: true,
                leaveOnEmpty: true,
                leaveOnEmptyCooldown: 5000,
                leaveOnEnd: true,
                leaveOnEndCooldown: 60000,
                pauseOnEmpty: true,
                preferBridgedMetadata: true,
                disableBiquad: true,
            },
            requestedBy: interaction.user,
            connectionOptions: {
                deaf: true,
            },
        });
        
        const embed = EmbedGenerator.Info({
            title: `${searchResult.hasPlaylist() ? 'Playlist' : 'Track'} Queued!`,
            thumbnail: { url: track.thumbnail },
            description: `[${track.title} by ${track.author}](${track.url})`,
            fields: searchResult.playlist
                ? [{ name: 'Playlist', value: searchResult.playlist.title }]
                : [],
            footer: {
                text: 'Powered by Novonode.',
                iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/911577673292210197/620156df19613565c1e71a39c4f71691.png',
            }
        });
        return interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        const embed = EmbedGenerator.Error({
            title: '',
            description: `❌ Something went wrong whilst playing \`${query}\`.`,
            footer: {
                text: '(ℹ️) Contact me on Discord IMMEDIATELY: jonno_aus',
            }
        });
        return interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
}

Expected result: Awaiting the player to finish the full track first.
